# instead of clicking on the element it clicks on the most top-left side of the window

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Java and Selenium to write a test. I have an element (a drop down menu) that I want to click on that I used `action.click`, `elemnet.clcik` `javascript executor`. But instead of the element they all click on the most top-left side of the window.
I opened developer tool window and checked my xpath that I finding the element with and it's correct, i mean when I copy paste the xpath at the DOM it shows the element. why do they click on top-left side of the window?

below is the snippet of the dom that the element is in there:

```
<div class="verde-form-row workflowTask-row even">
<h1><span class="by-label">Service</span>: Platinum <span class="unitOrLld">(Acres)</span></h1>
<form class="verde-form-fields fieldInfo-fields " data-task="">
    <div data-create-with="" class="form-field-wrapper task-create-with">
        <div class="select2-container select2-container-multi verde-select2 undefined" id="s2id_autogen11438">
            <ul class="select2-choices">
                <li class="select2-search-field">
                    <label for="s2id_autogen11439" class="select2-offscreen"></label>
                    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" class="select2-input select2-default" id="s2id_autogen11439" placeholder="" style="width: 290px;" aria-activedescendant="select2-result-label-11977"> </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <input data-selector="" type="hidden" name="field" value="" tabindex="-1" class="select2-offscreen">
    </div>
    <div class="create-task-info">
        <div class="task-comments">
            <input type="text" name="comments" placeholder="Comments" value="">
            <button type="button" data-action="cancel">Cancel</button>
        </div>
        <div class="task-lab">
            <div class="form-field-wrapper" data-field-area="">
                <input type="number" step="any" min="0" name="field_area" placeholder="Field Area" value="">
                <label class="task-field-area-unit" data-field-area-units="">Acres</label>
            </div>
            <div data-lab-priority="" class="form-field-wrapper">
                <div class="select2-container verde-select2 undefined select2-allowclear" id="s2id_autogen12036">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="select2-choice" tabindex="-1"> <span class="select2-chosen" id="select2-chosen-12037">Applied (Pre Buy)</span><abbr class="select2-search-choice-close"></abbr> <span class="select2-arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span>
                    </a>
                    <label for="s2id_autogen12037" class="select2-offscreen"></label>
                    <input class="select2-focusser select2-offscreen" type="text" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" aria-labelledby="select2-chosen-12037" id="s2id_autogen12037">
                    <div class="select2-drop select2-display-none select2-with-searchbox">
                        <div class="select2-search">
                            <label for="s2id_autogen12037_search" class="select2-offscreen"></label>
                            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" class="select2-input" role="combobox" aria-expanded="true" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="select2-results-12037" id="s2id_autogen12037_search" placeholder=""> </div>
                        <ul class="select2-results" role="listbox" id="select2-results-12037"> </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input data-selector="" type="hidden" name="lab_priority_type" value="11" tabindex="-1" title="" class="select2-offscreen">
            </div>
            <div data-lab-analysis="" class="form-field-wrapper"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

and this is my xpath:

```
//div[./h1[contains(text(),'Platinum')]]//span[text()='Applied (Pre Buy)']
```

a hint: when I click on any other parts of the window and then click on the element it works !!!

Comment: Provide more info like `HTML` for target element, `XPath` you used

Comment: @Andersson  i updated the question

Comment: Has your script been synchronized correctly before performing the click?

Comment: @Sai I wait before the click for 2 seconds

Comment: That's probably insufficient. Wait for the specific element to be clickable or for the moment increase the wait to allow the page to load fully